# C# List удалить элемент списка

Tags: c#, разработка-игр

Игра состоит из блоков `List<Block>`. И пуль `Bullet`.
При столкновение с пулей блок должен удаляться с экрана. 
Функцию столкновения я написал. Все работает.

```
 foreach (Block blocks in blockList){               
    blocks.colide(bulletList);
}
```

Но я не понимаю как удалить элемент списка Block так что бы это не приводило к ошибке. Я так понимаю при столкновении пули я должен получить id блока, чтобы его удалить. Потом перед отрисовкой проверять существует ли блок.
Можно удалить прямо в функции столкновения. Только когда я делаю RemoveAt с любым значением игра крашиться.

Comment: _Можно удалить_ - так можно или нельзя? Вероятно, там должно быть слово "нужно"? Тогда показывайте, как сделано удаление в методе "collide".

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < blockList.Count; i++)
{               
  if (blockList[i].collide(bulletList))
  {
    blockList.RemoveAt(i);
    i--;
  }
}
```

Comment: Попробую потом отпишусь.

Comment: можно удалить прямо в функции столкновения. Только когда я делаю RemoveAt с любым значением игра  крашиться.

Comment: @ItsGonnaBeMe  Запустите игру с дебаггером, посмотрите какую ощибку выдает